# C++ multi threading data structure for communication between two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, message-queue

I have a thread that calls various APIs of a COM interface. Now I want to invoke these functions from another thread. Can you please advise how I can achieve this?
How can I implement the communication between these two threads? If I define a Message queue sort of data structure which is common for these two threads then how do I define a common data structure as the parameters are different for each COM API.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more detail. Why do you need a message queue? COM calls are usually synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define one common data structure. There is a different data structure for each different function signature. Only common thing between those structures is identifier of the function. In your thread you'll have giant switch (or std::map) that would translate function identifier to function itself. After that you know how to interpret the rest of the structure. The structures should have POD semantic.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way is to use callbacks. You pass your data round via pointer. You can either use polymorphism to override the method that the base class calls when you pop it off the queue. Base calls function x, you override function x in derivative classes to achieve what you want.

Another way is to use plain old callbacks. You pass the address of your function onto a queue along with any data you need, wrapped up cleanly in a struct. All of the callbacks must have the same signature, so you'll probably need to cast your data to void.

Answer (score 1):

If each thread is running as a [single-threaded apartment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680112%28VS.85%29.aspx) then you can make calls on the required APIs from a remote thread by marshalling its interface pointer as an `IStream` from the object's owning thread to the other thread via [CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693316%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691421%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Once the remote thread has an interface pointer, you can make calls on it directly.

You might also be able to do this more simply using the [Global Interface Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682353%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), depending on your app's threading model.  This would be the easiest way.